# How do I set the dependencyResolutionManagement on init.gradle?

Tags: gradle, expo

I am trying to install a package but it seems to be going to https://jitpack.io/ which is having an outage at the moment.  I have a personal proxy repo which already has the image I want but because the dependent code has `42.2.+` it is looking for some other data which I think I also have but it is resolving to jitpack.

```bash
cat <<EOT > $HOME/.gradle/init.gradle
allprojects {
  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
      force "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.70.5"
    }
  }

  repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  maven {
    url = uri('https://mine/')
    credentials {
      ...
    }
  }
  <-- tried putting here
}
<-- and here
```

This is the block I wanted to add

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url = uri('https://mine/')
      credentials {
          ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it is saying signature not found.

There's a [closed issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15772) for this but I can't find an example on how to do it.  I tried to copy the one from the Issue OP but it didn't appear to work

```
settingsEvaluated {
  it.dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
      maven { 
        url = uri('https://mine/')
        credentials {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the end I get this

```
[RUN_GRADLEW] A problem occurred configuring project ':rn-pendo-sdk'.
[RUN_GRADLEW] > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':rn-pendo-sdk:implementation'.
[RUN_GRADLEW]    > Could not resolve sdk.pendo.io:pendoIO:2.19.+.
[RUN_GRADLEW]      Required by:
[RUN_GRADLEW]          project :rn-pendo-sdk
[RUN_GRADLEW]       > Failed to list versions for sdk.pendo.io:pendoIO.
[RUN_GRADLEW]          > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://www.jitpack.io/sdk/pendo/io/pendoIO/maven-metadata.xml.
[RUN_GRADLEW]             > Could not GET 'https://www.jitpack.io/sdk/pendo/io/pendoIO/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 521 from server:
```

Comment: The error is saying that `sdk.pendo.io:pendoIO:2.19.+` can't be resolved. The [Pendo docs say that this dependency is in a pendo.io repository](https://support.pendo.io/hc/en-us/articles/4404065352987-Developer-s-Guide-to-Installing-the-Pendo-Android-SDK#install-the-sdk-0-1). Have you tried adding the https://software.mobile.pendo.io/artifactory/androidx-release repository?

Comment: I have it on my repo already.  It had worked before but stopped when jitpack.io went down.

Comment: Ah okay, I see. If a repository becomes inaccessible then Gradle might decide to fail the build, [to help with reproducibility](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html#repository_disabling). What you could do is [filter the Pendo repository](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:repository-content-filtering), so that Gradle won't check JitPack for the `sdk.pendo.io:pendoIO` dependency.

Comment: It's not really something I can do since it's Expo EAS that builds all the gradle stuff.  All I can do is shove in an init.gradle.

At the moment the jitpack.io is up so there's no more build issue to help recreate the problem.